# Infinite duplication of laravel view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am having a weird problem with laravel and couldn't find any solution to it.

I have a route in my web

`Route::get('/tasks', 'TaskController@index')->name('tasks');`

My Task controller is as follows

```
class TaskController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('todos.show');

    }
}
```

It executes fine, but when I add a parameter in the route and the function, the view laravel is loading just keep duplicating itself infinitely.

`Route::get('/tasks/{list_id}', 'TaskController@index')->name('tasks');`

and in controller

```
    public function index($list_id)
    {
        return view('todos.show');

    }
```

The view file contains nothing, just extending the main view. Here is the code in view file.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')

@endsection
```

**EDIT**
Contents of `RouteServiceprovider`

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }


    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();
    }

    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it gets duplicated? You get the output multiple times? It never finish loading? How are you accessing the URL, AJAX? What's the content of `RouteServiceProvider`? And the layout?

Comment: You got it right. I get output multiple times. No ajax, simple in the browser. I never touched the `RouteServiceProvider`. Still updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is,, viewing a list item of particular id and showing it in a view... If it is then,

```
public function index($list_id)
{
$listitem = YourModel::find($id);
return view('todos.show', compact('listitem'));
}
```

and show it in a view file...

Comment: Yes it is what I am trying to do, and I know how to do it :), but this will come at a later stage. At the moment I am having problem rendering the view. As I said it keeps duplicating itself just by adding the parameter.